# AngularJS watch on Html Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and stuck in one issue.

I have a requirement of fixed Table Header but a scrollable Body.
I tried using simple css approach but alignment with header was a problem I am running on.

So I came across Angular Directive,
[Scrollable Table Directive](https://www.pointblankdevelopment.com.au/blog/angularjs-fixed-header-scrollable-table-directive)

Directive

```
validationApp.directive('fixedHeader', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            tableHeight: '@'
        },
        link: function ($scope, $elem, $attrs, $ctrl) {
            // wait for content to load into table and the tbody to be visible
            $scope.$watch(function () { return $elem.find("tbody").is(':visible'); },
                function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    alert("visible directive");
                    if (newValue === true) {
                        // reset display styles so column widths are correct when measured below
                        $elem.find('thead, tbody, tfoot').css('display', '');

                        // wrap in $timeout to give table a chance to finish rendering
                        $timeout(function () {

                            // set widths of columns
                            $elem.find('th').each(function (i, thElem) {
                                thElem = $(thElem);
                                var tdElems = $elem.find('tbody tr:first td:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')');
                                var tfElems = $elem.find('tfoot tr:first td:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')');

                                var columnWidth = tdElems.width();
                                thElem.width(columnWidth);
                                tdElems.width(columnWidth);
                                tfElems.width(columnWidth);
                            });



                            // set css styles on thead and tbody
                            $elem.find('thead, tfoot').css({
                                'display': 'block',
                            });

                            $elem.find('tbody').css({
                                'display': 'block',
                               /* 'height': $scope.tableHeight || '200px',*/
                                'overflow': 'auto'
                            });


                            // reduce width of last column by width of scrollbar
                            var scrollBarWidth = $elem.find('thead').width() - $elem.find('tbody')[0].clientWidth;
                            if (scrollBarWidth > 0) {
                                // for some reason trimming the width by 2px lines everything up better
                                scrollBarWidth -= 2;
                                $elem.find('tbody tr:first td:last-child').each(function (i, elem) {
                                    $(elem).width($(elem).width() - scrollBarWidth);
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Table

```
<table id="tableDataOfUsers" width="100%" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed" ng-show="users.length" fixed-header style="border: 1">
        <thead id="tableHeaderOfUsers">
            <tr style="font-weight: bold">
                <th style="width: 30%;"><label ><b>{{ 'load.static.usersetup.NAME_COLUMN_USER_TABLE' | translate }}</b></label></th>
                <th style="width: 30%;"><label ><b>{{ 'load.static.usersetup.EXTENSION_COLUMN_USER_TABLE' | translate }}</b></label></th>
                <th style="width: 30%;"><label><b>{{ 'load.static.usersetup.PROFILENAME' | translate }}</b></label></th>
                <th style="width: 10%;" ng-show="!usrreadonly"><label><b><span ng-show="form.userSetupForm.$visible"></span></b></label></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tableBodyOfUsers">
            <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:filterUser" style="height: 35px;">
                <td title="{{ 'load.static.usersetup.USR_AG_TITLE' | translate }}" style="width: 30%;">
                  <!-- editable username (text with validation) -->
                  <span editable-text="user.name" e-form="form.userSetupForm" e-required onbeforesave="checkDuplicateUsers($data, user.id)" ng-readonly="usrreadonly">
                    {{ user.name || '' }}
                  </span>
                </td>

                <td title="{{ 'load.static.usersetup.USR_AGEXTN_TITLE' | translate }}" style="width: 30%;">
                  <!-- editable username (text with validation) -->
                  <span editable-textnumeric="user.extn" e-minlength="1" e-maxlength="4" e-form="form.userSetupForm" onbeforesave="checkDuplicateExtension($data, user.id)" e-required ng-readonly="usrreadonly">
                    {{ user.extn || '' }}
                  </span>
                </td>

                <td title="{{ 'load.static.usersetup.USR_AG_PRO_TITLE' | translate }}" style="width: 30%;">
                  <!-- editable group (select-remote) -->
                   <span editable-select="user.profileid" e-form="form.userSetupForm" onshow="loadProfiles()"  onbeforesave="checkProfile($data, user.profileid)" e-ng-options="g.id as g.name for g in profiles" ng-readonly="usrreadonly">
                    {{ showProfiles(user) }}
                  </span>
                </td>

                <td title="{{ 'load.static.table.TAB_DEL' | translate }}" ng-show="!usrreadonly" style="width: 10%;">
                    <button type="button" ng-show="form.userSetupForm.$visible" ng-click="deleteUser($index)" class="deletebutton" ng-disabled="usrreadonly"></button>
                </td>
            </tr>           
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Initially my table displays like this
[image: Initally Table displays like this]

Now when I click on delete button on any row except first, it deletes correctly without alignment issues, but when I delete first row it then start giving alignment issues and displays like

[image: Table display only after deleting first row]

I knew the issue is with my watch in directive 
`function () { return $elem.find("tbody").is(':visible'); }` it watches only when table initially get visible, so it run only once.

that is why only first row of my table is getting proper width in "px", other rows get the width in "%" ie set on table.

How can I make this table watch every time when I add any row or delete any row.
Or how can I make this directive to assign all the rows width in "px".

Comment: I just tried adding third parameter to true, but still the result is same. actually my directive watch is called only once. I want to make it call every time when I add row or delete row.

Comment: use deep watch but it can cause perform issues... You can do it by adding true as third parameter to your watch...         $scope.$watch(function () { return $elem.find("tbody").is(':visible'); },
              function (newValue, oldValue) {},
              true);

Comment: I have mentioned in first comment that I tried it but no success.

Comment: How about a new parameter for the directive (on the scope, using `=`) that will hold the number of rows, and you'll watch that ? Should trigger everytime the row number changes.

Comment: Hi Omri, can you please help me with syntax as I am new to AngularJS. I tried the same by reading some blogs but some or other syntax error.

Comment: Im applying changes... let me check..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is keep another scope variable that holds the number of rows for instance, and pass that to the directive. Watch that, and it will change accordingly.

Add to HTML:

```
<table fixed-header rows="numberOfRows">...</table>
```

Controller function that adds a new user:

```
$scope.addNewUser = function () {
        $scope.data.push({name: $scope.newName, age: $scope.newAge });
        $scope.numberOfRows++;
    }
```

Change to directive:

```
scope: {
            tableHeight: '@',
            rows: "="
        },
```

And the watch:

```
$scope.$watch(function () { return $scope.rows },
```

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vy0oy4tg/1/) as a demonstration.

Comment: Thanks a lot Omri... it worked by little bit modification as per my business logic ... Thanks once again..